# Does OCaml/ReasonML have support for DSLs in the core language or core libraries?

Tags: ocaml, dsl, reason

Languages, like Groovy, Kotlin and Scala, offer support to DSLs out of the box (Ex: [Groovy DSL](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html) and [Kotlin Type-Safer Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html)). Does OCaml/ReasonML have support for DSLs in their core language or core libraries?

Comment: Yes, they're called functions! IME plain functions work just fine for most DSLs I've needed. Half-jokes aside though, "DSL" is much too broad and vague to be able to answer sufficiently I think. You should try to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this is the main power of functional programming so it would be surprising that you can't do this in OCaml. It is so natural to ML, that there is no need for any special tooling or techniques.

Let's give some examples. I will start with the library which I author, it is called [Ogre](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/ogre/ogre.mli#L216) and it provides a typesafe query language fully embedded in OCaml with the OCaml typechecker verifying that queries are well-typed. Here are some examples.

1. Select all students that have the GPA rate greater than 3.8.

   ```
   select
     ~where:(student.(gpa) > float 3.8)
     (from students)
   ```
2. Select all students and their corresponding teachers, that have a GPA greater than 3.8 (assuming that teacher is a foreign key to the table of teachers).

   ```
   select
     ~where:(student.(gpa) > float 3.8)
     ~join:[[field teacher ~from:student; field id ~from:teacher]]
     (from students)
   ```
3. The following SQL statement

   ```
   SELECT name FROM students WHERE gpa > 3.5
   ```

is expressed as,

```
    foreach Query.(select
                     ~where:(student.(gpa) > float 3.8)
                     (from students))
      ~f:(fun s -> return (Student.name s))
```

A good resource on writing eDSL in OCaml is Oleg's [ML](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/index.html#DSLs) page. Another example, is a eDSL for writing [CI/CD pipelines](https://github.com/talex5/ocurrent). And, of course, I can't miss [TyXML](https://ocsigen.org/tyxml/4.4.0/manual/intro), but this is a slightly different story. Anyway, there are tons of other examples, but I hope it is enough to get the feeling.